# What's the relationship with ServerServiceDefinition and a concrete class?

Tags: java, grpc, distributed-system, grpc-java

I am learning to use grpc recently and feel confused  about one thing after I instantiated a Server class named server:

```
server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port)
            .addService(new MetadataStoreImpl(this.config, port))
            .executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads))
            .build()
            .start();
```

I read the java doc and found the ServerBuilder.addService:

```
public abstract T addService(ServerServiceDefinition service);
```

In this case, I use my own class "MetadataStoreImpl" to replace "ServerServiceDefinition" but still don't know why. Moreover,how can I get reference the member variable of this MetadataStoreImpl class from class server?
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `MetadataStoreImpl` extends a generated service stub (e.g., `MetadataStoreImplBase`) then it will implement gRPC's `BindableService` interface. `ServerBuilder` has another [`addService`](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerBuilder.html#addService-io.grpc.BindableService-) method that accepts a `BindableService` instead of a `ServerServiceDefinition`. [Here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/9a502ecf0b909949f1e6175448f3a7e4d19b3378/services/src/generated/main/grpc/io/grpc/health/v1/HealthGrpc.java#L91) is an example of our generated code's implementation of the `bindService` method, which just builds and returns a `ServerServiceDefinition`.

For your second question, you can get a list of `ServerServiceDefinitions` via [`Server#getServices`](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Server.html#getServices--), but this won't directly give you back your original `MetadataStoreImpl`, but rather the `ServerServiceDefinition` returned by the generated code's `bindService` method. Typically, you wouldn't use `getServices`, as you'd just retain a reference to your service after you added it to the builder.

You can find more information gRPC Java's generated code at https://grpc.io/docs/reference/java/generated-code.html.